# Show that $A$ cannot be embedded into any countable union of closed nowhere dense subsets in $X$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X=A\cup B$ be a complete metric space. Assume that $B$ is a countable union of closed nowhere dense subsets of $X$.

Show that $A$ cannot be embedded in any countable union of closed nowhere
dense subsets in $X.$

What I have so far:

Suppose $f:A\to \bigcup_{n\ge 1}F_n$ is an embedding of $A$ into $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}F_n,$ where $F_n$ is closed and nowhere dense in $X.$

Then $$A=f^{-1}(\bigcup_{n\ge 1}F_n)=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}f^{-1}(F_n).$$

Since $F_n$ is closed in $X,$ it is closed in $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}F_n,$ and so $f^{-1}(F_n)$ is closed in $A.$ So we can write $f^{-1}(F_n)=C_n\cap A,$ where $C_n$ is a closed set in $X.$ It follows that $A\subset \bigcup_{n\ge 1}C_n,$ and so $X=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}C_n\cup B.$

The contradiction will thus be obtained if I can show that the $C_n$'s are nowhere dense (by Baire). How can I show this? Or is there another way to attempt this question?

Comment: What do you mean by an "embedding"? For instance, if $X=\mathbb R$ (so $X$ is a complete metric space), and if $B=\mathbb Q\cup C$ where $C$ is the Cantor set (so $B$ is a countable union of closed nowhere dense subsets), and $A$ is the set of all irrational numbers (so $X=A\cup B$, then $A$ is **homeomorphically** embeddable in $B.$ What kind of embeddings are you talking about?

Comment: @bof The embedding I'm talking about is defined this way (taken from Wikipedia): an injective continuous map $f:X\to Y$ between topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ is an embedding if $f$ yields a homeomorphism between $X$ and $f(X)$ (where $f(X)$ carries the subspace topology inherited from $Y$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Counterexample.** The closed unit interval $X=[0,1]$ is a complete metric smace. Let $B=X\cap\mathbb Q,$ the set of all rational numbers in $X;$ and let $A=X\setminus\mathbb Q,$ the set of all irrational numbers in $X.$ Thus $X=A\cup B;$ and $B,$ being a countable set, is a countable union of closed nowhere dense sets. The Cantor set $C$ is a closed nowhere dense set; I claim that $A$ is homeomorphically embeddable in $C.$

**I.** If you happen to know that $C$ is homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ and $A$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb N^\mathbb N,$ you can simply observe that there is an obvious embedding of $\mathbb N$ into $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N,$ and therefore there is an embedding of $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ (which is homeomorphic to $A$) into $(\{0,1\}^\mathbb N)^\mathbb N,$ which is homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N\times\mathbb N},$ which is homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N,$ which is homeomorphic to $C.$

**II.** Each number $x\in A=X\setminus\mathbb Q$ can be represented uniquely in the form
$$x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\varepsilon_n}{2^n},\ \varepsilon_n\in\{0,1\};$$
and you can verify that the function
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2\varepsilon_n}{3^n}$$
maps $A$ homeomorphically onto a subspace of $C.$

Comment: Great counterexample! What kind of "embedding" should we be talking about then, so that $A$ cannot be "embedded" in any countable union of closed nowhere dense subsets in $X$?

Comment: I don't know. Can you ask whoever gave you the problem for a clarification?

Comment: Wait! You said that $A$ can be embedded in $C,$ but the question asks that $A$ cannot be embedded in a countable union(!) of closed nowhere dense subsets in $X$!

Comment: $A$ can also be embedded in $B\cup C,$ which is a countable union of closed nowhere dense sets.

Comment: Ahh of course! Very much appreciated!